# Doctrine Querybuilder doesnt return exact matches

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine

I have and api endpoint which should return a user based on his id : `user/{id}`.

In my controller i have the following code:

```
/**
 * @Api\Get("user/{id}")
 * @SWG\Parameter(name="id", type="string", in="path", required=true)
 */
public function getUser(Request $request, string $id) {
    $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('App\Entity\User')->findUser($id);
    return $this->view($user);
}
```

In my repository i have the following code:

```
public function findUser(string $id) {
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
    $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('a.id',':id'))->setParameter('id',$id);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

it is working fine when getting `user/4`, but it is also working when getting `user/4ruqbu`.

I just want to get the user on `user/4` and no result on `user/4ruqbu`. It should return the exact match. I think the problem is that the id parameter is a string. if i change it to int it is working, but i get an error instead of no result if i try `user/4eiugq`.

Is there a way to handle that?

Comment: Could you post you controller and service?

Comment: @DariusMann i edited my post and added the code for controller and the whole function in my repo

Comment: What is your Symfony version ?

Comment: @AymDev i have Symfony 5.3.9 installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your route accepts any string for your `id` parameter which means that any value will make its way to your repository method. Then if you try to use a string which starts with a numeric value as an integer, you will get that integer.
Try for yourself on [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org):

```php
var_dump((int)'4ruqbu');    // output: int(4)
```

You could make use of [parameters validation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#parameters-validation) using a Regex:

```php
/**
 * @Api\Get("user/{id<\d+>}")
 */
public function getUser(Request $request, int $id) {
    // ...
}
```

This should now fail for URIs such as **/user/4ruqbu** as it does not meet the route requirements.

---

Some improvements:

If you installed [sensio/framework-extra-bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/sensio/framework-extra-bundle) you can benefit of the [ParamConverter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#parameter-conversion) and replace `string $id` with a user:

```php
public function getUser(User $user, Request $request)
{
    // ...
}
```

Avoid fetching services related to **Doctrine** with `$this->getDoctrine()` etc. Use autowiring instead.
If you need the **Entity Manager** to save/update/remove entities, add a `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface` argument to your controller method. If you need to query for entities using a repository, add an argument typed with its class like `App\Repository\UserRepository` in your case:

```php
// Example of controller method fetching services by autowiring:
public function myAction(EntityManagerInterface $em, UserRepository $userRepo)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i dont understand why sending a string to my repository function will break. `$qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('a.id',':id'))->setParameter('id',$id);`  should only return an exact match, but its acting like `LIKE`

Comment: @mrJQuery I never said it would break. Your current code works with a string without breaking. I was just explaining *why* it works with strings like `'4ruqbu'` ;-)

Comment: @mrJQuery I didn't see the edit of your comment, sorry. I don't think that it acts like a `LIKE`, but that Doctrine probably converts the value internally to an integer, which truncates the value to the number at its beginning as I explained in my answer.